# Oreo - Prevent ACTION_GET_CONTENT from using built-in Files app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

My app reads information from a file selected by the user (then does weird and wonderful things with it!). To make this simple, the "file explorer" app is pointed to a specific starting directory (where the app had previously stored such files).

This works fine, **except on my Oreo phone** (Nexus5) where the built-in Google app, Files, is always initiated, even in the presence of alternate file manager apps. **Files does not respond to the intent's uri**; consequently, the user has to navigate to the directory every time. Here's the relevant code:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            +  "/Documents/" + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
   intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");

   try {
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"), request_code);
   }
   catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
   {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

I've searched high and low for a solution, in vain. How can this be fixed?

Options I am interested in:

1. Disabling Files
2. Preventing the Intent from using Files
3. Talking to Files so that it opens the specified directory
4. Forcing the Intent to use a different file explorer app (that would be an app's preference)
5. Any other solution that does not involve the use of a file chooser library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To make this simple, the "file explorer" app is pointed to a specific starting directory (where the app had previously stored such files).

There is no `Intent` action for this, sorry.

> This works fine, except on my Oreo phone (Nexus5)

It will fail on hundreds of millions of devices. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri`. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT):

> Note that no URI is supplied in the intent, as there are no constraints on where the returned data originally comes from.

Also note that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not necessarily have to involve a file explorer, and a device does not have to have a file explorer app.

> Files does not respond to the intent's uri;

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementations are not supposed to respond to the `Uri`.

> Any other solution that does not involve the use of a file chooser library

Write your own file chooser UI. Or, eliminate the functionality from your app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, depressing though it is. The link to the documentation suggests some sort of searches are possible (e.g. ACTION_VIEW content://contacts/people/1 -- Display information about the person whose identifier is "1".). Would something similar be possible with ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Comment: @RudyF: No. `ACTION_VIEW` is documented to take a `Uri`. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not. It is only for finding content by MIME type. `ACTION_PICK` takes a `Uri`, but it is supposed to only be for `content` `Uri` values (e.g., for picking a contact). `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` has `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` to specify a starting point, but that once again is for `content` `Uri` values (specifically from past interactions with the Storage Access Framework) and only works on API Level 19+. I know you don't like the answer, but a file chooser library is probably your best bet.